# Hi, I want to know how to add data to the end of a table in matlab

Tags: matlab

[image]

I want to add another date_time element as well as another cups_out element to the end of this table.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation works for table arrays. So if you create a table array with the date/time element and cups out that you want to add then you can do,

```
FinalTable = [CupIntData; AdditionalDataTable];
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as concatenation, you can also index off the `end` in the way you would for a regular numeric array. `table` allows you to provide a `cell` array, and it knows how to do the right thing:

```
>> t = table(datetime, 1);
>> t(end+1,:) = {datetime, 2}
t =
  2×2 table
            Var1            Var2
    ____________________    ____
    28-Sep-2022 09:51:56     1  
    28-Sep-2022 09:52:07     2
```